# python: how to sort list by all keys?

Tags: python

Here, I want to write a function to sort `a`.

I want to sort `a` like this.

```
a = [[1,3,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,2],[2,3,1]]
def sort(a, sort_index):
  if len(set([_[sort_index] for _ in a])) < len(a):
    key_list = [sort_index] + [i for i in range(len(a[0]))]
    # sort by multi keys.
    a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: (x[i] for i in range(key_list)))
return a
sort(a,0)
```

Here, `sort_index` is the first important index. If the value is same in `sort_index`, other indexes would be considered.
So, the result is expected:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,3,1],[2,3,2]]
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the result with sort_index = 1 ? Should other indices be considered in order?

Comment: Here, `sort_index` should be considered first,  the order of other indices is not important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to sort based on an arbitrary permutation of the sublists, you can specify a key that consists of the desired element as well as the original sublist.

```
def sort(a, sort_index):
    return sorted(a, key=lambda x: (x[sort_index], x))
```

If you *do* want to sort on arbitrary permutations, make `sort_index` an iterable of indices.

```
def sort(a, sort_indices=None):
    if sort_indices is None:
        # Duplicate the natural sort order of the sublists
        # Assumes a is not empty and all sublists have the same length.
        sort_indices = list(range(len(a[0]))
    return sorted(a, key=lambda x: tuple(x[i] for i in sort_indices)

sort(a, [0])
sort(a, [2, 1])
# etc.
```

Comment: If it is just from sort_index onward you could use `lambda x: (x[sort_index:], x)` (edit: fixed typo)

Comment: `x[sort_index:]`, but yes :)